# Convert one column to numbers

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a program I am building which asks for a csv file and saves it in excel. I have one column that is currency - $10.00 - I can convert other cells to number with my code but I assume since there is a '$' before the numbers it does not convert. How can I fix this for just this one column - Thanks

```
def open_csv():
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
import csv
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter

Tk().withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename()

open_rawdata = open(filename, 'r')

csv.register_dialect('commas', delimiter=',')

reader = csv.reader(open_rawdata, dialect='commas')

wb = Workbook()
dest_xls = r'C:\Users\sparkis\Desktop\WeeklyReport.xlsx'

ws = wb.worksheets[0]
ws.title = "TEST TITLE"

for row_index, row in enumerate(reader):
    for column_index, cell in enumerate(row):
        column_letter = get_column_letter((column_index + 1))
        s = cell
        try:
            s = float(s)
        except ValueError:
            pass

        ws.cell('%s%s'%(column_letter, (row_index + 1))).value = s



wb.save(filename = dest_xls)
```

Answer (score 1):

In a CSV file **all** values are strings. openpyxl workbooks have an [option that will let them do type inference](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html?highlight=guess_types#using-number-formats) but you are better managing the conversion yourself and, in this case, adding an appropriate number format.

Assuming it is the fourth column of your input that needs converting to a number. Something along the lines of this should work.

```
for idx, row in enumerate(reader, 1):
    row[3] = row[3][1:] # strip $
    ws.append(row)
    ws.cell(idx, 4).number_format = "$"
```